# A question on a proof of the existence of non-measurable sets

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

This is an excerpt of Rosenthal's book: "A First look at Rigorous Probability Theory" and contains an important theorem in the development of measure theory. While I generally understand the proof well, there is a point that I find confusing, namely why does he take out $0$ from $H$. Could you please enlighten me as to the reason? Thank you.

[image]

The r-shifts are defined as,

[image]

Comment: Maybe it comes up later in the proof? It is not really relevant in the excerpt you have presented here. Given that the author uses the phrase "for definiteness", this assumption is probably not that important but merely simplifies some technicality later on in the argument. (Indeed I happen to know that this assumption is not important because I have seen essentially the same proof carried out with no such hypothesis.)

Comment: @Ian Hi Ian, thank you for your response, I have now included the entire proof.

Comment: I think this proof is technically wrong, even though it has the right general idea. The rational shifts of $H$ need not be contained inside $(0,1]$. For example, if $1/2 \in H$ then $H+2/3$, i.e. $\{ h+2/3 : h \in H \}$, is not contained in $(0,1]$. Perhaps $\oplus$ means something different than I anticipate, like $A \oplus r=\{ a+r \mod 1 : a \in A \}$. The way I have usually seen this proof presented, you have that the shifts are contained in a slightly larger set like $[-1,2]$.

Comment: @iAN But the r-shifts are modulo-one, see the edited post.

Comment: I see. Then I guess the point of not having $0 \in H$ is so that the union is $(0,1]$ rather than $[0,1]$ (so assuming $0 \not \in H$ allows the author to avoid some case work).

Comment: @Ian Okay, that makes sense mathematicians are a lazy breed :P. If you like, you can post this as an answer so I can mark it as the correct one.

Comment: It appears that the author does not want to confuse the equivalence class $0 \in H$ with the set shift $H \bigoplus 0.$

Comment: I am not quite confident enough in my guess to be willing to formulate it as an answer. Some additional comments by others are welcomed.