# Proving the existence of a non-measurable set

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm asking the same question as raised in [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952440/a-question-on-a-proof-of-the-existence-of-non-measurable-sets). There hasn't been an answer yet, so can someone please help?

I did read the comments. One of the comments says the following

> I see. Then I guess the point of not having $0 \in H$ is so that the union
> is $(0,1]$ rather than $[0,1]$ (so assuming $0$ not in $H$ allows the author to avoid
> some case work).

What case work is there to do? The equivalence class of $0$ is essentially the set of rationals between $[0,1]$. What additional work is there to do even if I include $0$ in $H$?

Separately, I wanted to ask: in the proof, Rosenthal uses "for definiteness". What does "definiteness" mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He has defined $\oplus$ so that it’s not quite the usual addition mod $1$: it takes values in $(0,1]$ instead of in $[0,1)$. If we had $0\in H$, we’d have to take

$$\bigcup_{r\in\color{red}{(0,1]}\cap\Bbb Q}(H\oplus r)$$

to get a cover of $(0,1]$ instead of Rosenthal’s

$$\bigcup_{r\in\color{red}{[0,1)}\cap\Bbb Q}(H\oplus r)\;.$$

To avoid having to deal both with the case $0\in H$ and the case $0\notin H$ he chooses one of them. His *For definiteness* is just saying that he’s pinning down one possibility for the representative of the rationals, and at that point the reader can reasonably suspect that this is because the choice makes some minor technical difference to the argument, as is the case here. Where he says *For definiteness* I’d probably had said *Without loss of generality*.

Comment: Why can't one just use $[0,1]$? That is, replace $\mathbb{P}( (0,1])$ with $\mathbb{P}( [0,1])$ and use $[0,1]$ in the subscript of that union discussed in your reply?

Comment: @user1691278: Because $H\oplus 0=H\oplus 1$, and he wants the shifts of $H$ to be pairwise disjoint.